# HTML Video not appearing on the page

Tags: html, video

I'm wanting figure out Why my html video is not appearing on my web page. I have html code below showing the file that I want to show on my website but now working.

```
<video height="369px" width="610px" class="detailVideo" src="/assets/video/bjp__video.mp4"></video>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the browser's dev tools for errors, or to see if the path to the video is correct?

Comment: The path name is correct don't see any browser anything has error

Answer (score 0):

Kindly correct file path. Or put the video on the same file as your index.html.